# Canon 5d III: no button works in manual modes

Tags: canon-5d-mark-iii

Something weird is happening with my 5D III, I'll try to explain.
In manual modes (M, AV, Tv, P) I can't change any option or adjustments (aperture, iso...) shutter is fixed at 50 and nothing happens if I press menu, info or any other button. I can't display previous taken photos... nothing. The only thing I can change is the aperture with the top dial (instead of the back dial). The lock switch is off.
I can not go to live view or record video either. Im pretty sure is not a malfunction and I might have change something because the camera seems to work fine.
There's also something I've never seen, in the digital display instead of 1 bar for exposure there are two.
Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Not that I have the slightest clue what the problem is (I never encountered any of this), but what is your current firmware version? Are you using Magic Lantern?

Answer (score 3):

With multiple lines on the exposure compensation/light meter, it sounds like you have AEB (Auto Exposure Bracketing) enabled.

You won't be able to change anything until you complete the AEB sequence.

With the EOS 5D Mark III, an AEB sequence can be anywhere from two, three, five, or seven frames, depending on the setting selected for [C.Fn1 :Exposure → Number of bracketed shots].